# Can I use data attributes as post data in .load() calls?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Can I use a data attribute to pass a variable into jQuery .load()?

```
<div class="myClass" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="myClass" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="myClass" data-id="3"></div>

<script>
$('.myClass').load('my.php',{pk:$(this).data('id')});
</script>
```

`$_POST['pk']` always ends up as undefined.

Comment: what is context of `this`? As it is shown it would be the `window`

Comment: May have oversimplified for the question perhaps. Its within a $(document).ready but I'll have a think about the context and see if I find my mistake.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, look at http://api.jquery.com/load/ at the section marked **Request Method**. I think it would be using `POST` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".myClass").each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.load("my.php", {pk: el.data("id)});
});
```